# Redirect https to http for certain pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I want to redirect https requests to http for all but login and register pages.

So https:// example.com would redirect to http:// example.com but example.com/user/login should always redirect to https://example.com/user/login.

How do I do that in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the current request uses https using the `%{HTTPS}` variable in mod_rewrite. This is either `on` or `off`. Please note that the redirect you want will not have the intended behaviour for post requests, since the redirected url will always be requested using get without the post-body.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/(login|register)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^user/(login|register)$ https://example.com/user/$1 [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` after testing the redirect works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. The redirection from https to http works but it's redirecting me to example.com/index.php?a=user/login instead of https://example.com/user/login.

Comment: Place redirect rules *before* any internal rewrites you are doing. When the redirect flag is set, the request is redirected after the end of a cycle (which we end with the `L` flag).